# what is best ways to set loading/progress in full screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to add full-screen loading with the grey background when starting loading for `FullScreen` covered in it.

In Past, I used the `Stack` widget for it but the stack was not covered my App bar.

and I think to add `Scaffold` in `Stack` widget is not a good way to do this

Comment: You can try stack over scaffold widget.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try the following

Have a utils class

```
    class Utils {
      late BuildContext context;

      Utils(this.context);

    // this is where you would do your fullscreen loading
      Future<void> startLoading() async {
        return await showDialog<void>(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return const SimpleDialog(
              elevation: 0.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // can change this to your prefered color
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }

      Future<void> stopLoading() async {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
      Future<void> showError(Object? error) async {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Dismiss',
          onPressed: () {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        content: Text(handleError(error)),
      ),
    );
  }
      }
```

Then use it where you need loading

```
ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          
                          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                          if (widget.formkey!.currentState!.validate()) {
                            Utils(context).startLoading();
                            widget.formkey!.currentState!.save();
                            widget.authProvider
                                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                    widget.textController.text.trim(),
                                    widget.passwordController.text.trim())
                                .then((user) async {
                              // do something with user
                               Utils(context).stopLoading();
                            }).onError(
                              (error, stackTrace) {
                                Utils(context).showError(error);
                                Utils(context).stopLoading();
                              },
                            );
                          }
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          AppConstants.kBtnLogin,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      )
```

Comment: What if I called `Utils(context).stopLoading();` without `Utils(context).startLoading();`?
the current screen will be popped

Comment: @AbdallahA.Odeh You are correct, the startLoading must be called before the stopLoading.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a showDialog() will make sure that it covers appBar inside Scaffold, add this when you want the loader to appear:

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
```

Comment: I voted for this answer as it's simple and worked great for me

Answer (score 0):

Solution if you are using GetX:

```
class LoadingFullscreen {

    static void startLoading() {
      Get.dialog(
        const SimpleDialog(
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
            )
          ],
        )
      );
    }

    static stopLoading() {
      Get.close(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Center(
   child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

Expanded(
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
],
),
);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).